# Spark: How to access elements when type GenericRowWithSchema

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am trying to parse the JSON array but get the below error.  Any suggestions?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row, SparkSession}
import scala.collection.mutable

case class MyData(c1: String, c2: String)

object ParseJSON extends App {
  val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder().master("local[2]").getOrCreate()
  val sc = sparkSess.sparkContext

  val dfJSON: Dataset[Row] = sparkSess.read.format("json").option("multiLine", true).option("inferSchema", true).load("C:/test.json")

  dfJSON.printSchema()

  import sparkSess.implicits._
  val dfParsed = dfJSON.flatMap(rec => {
    val header = rec.getAs("Subject").asInstanceOf[Row].asInstanceOf[Row].getAs("Header").asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Seq[Row]]]
    header.flatten.foreach(t => {
      println(t.get(0) + " " + t.get(1))
    })
    Seq(MyData("", ""))
  })
  dfParsed.show(5000, false)
}
```

**test.json**

> {     "Subject": {        "Header": [             {
> "units": "k1",
> "label": "l1"           },          {
> "units": "k2",
> "label": "l2"           },          {
> "units": "k3",
> "label": "l3"           }       ]   } }

```
21/06/13 01:51:47 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to class scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce (org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema and scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(GenericTraversableTemplate.scala:172)
    at scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate$$anonfun$flatten$1.apply(GenericTraversableTemplate.scala:171)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate$class.flatten(GenericTraversableTemplate.scala:171)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatten(Traversable.scala:104)
    at ParseJSON$$anonfun$2.apply(ParseJSON.scala:32)
    at ParseJSON$$anonfun$2.apply(ParseJSON.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:645)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1289)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed with the casting change, see below.

From

```
val header = rec.getAs("Subject").asInstanceOf[Row].asInstanceOf[Row].getAs("Header").asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Seq[Row]]]
```

To

```
val header = rec.getAs("Subject").asInstanceOf[Row].asInstanceOf[Row].getAs("Header").asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Row]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the output you want is a `dataFrame` with `unit` and `label`.

```
df
  .withColumn("newHeader", explode(col("Subject.Header")))
  .select(col("newHeader.label").as("label"), col("newHeader.units").as("units"))
.show(false)


+-----+-----+
|label|units|
+-----+-----+
|l1   |k1   |
|l2   |k2   |
|l3   |k3   |
+-----+-----+
```

Another way could be you pass it to a UDF and inside udf :

```
header
.map(element => element.getAs[String]("units"))
.toList
```